# Is websocket Session#setMaxTextMessageBufferSize slow and can I set it dynamically

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I have a bunch(about 6...say **B1-B6**), of tomcat containers hooked up via websockets to a tomcat container say **C** which hosts a control panel application.

They send updates to **C** regularly via websockets and **C** sends commands to them via websockets also.

I have set `session.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize` to 10KB in the onOpen method of the `ServerEndPoint` and the `ClientEndPoint` classes.

Messaging works fine, but sometimes some data is generated whose size exceeds the Maximum TextMessage BufferSize of the sessions.

I had an idea to do something like:

```
 public boolean write(String message) {

        Worker w = this;//This is the Worker class, so i can do `this`

        while (!w.getSessions().isEmpty()) {
            //Ask for a session
            Session session = w.getSessions().poll();

            if (session != null) {
                //Session granted
                synchronized (session) {
                    int defaultBufferSize = session.getMaxTextMessageBufferSize();
                    int bytesToTransmit = message.getBytes().length;
                    if (defaultBufferSize <= bytesToTransmit) {
                        //increase the maximum buffer size to accomodate large messages
                        session.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(bytesToTransmit + 16);
                    }

                    try {
                        //send your message in peace?
                        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
                        //return connection to the pool.
                        w.getSessions().offer(session);
                               //Reset to the default buffer size to ..maybe reclaim memory?
                        session.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(defaultBufferSize);
                        return true;
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace(); 
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
```

That is, compare the byte size of the text to be transmitted with the max buffer size of the session and if the session cannot accomodate it, increase the session's buffer size.

However I have a deep seated suspicion that this might not work for some weird reason.

1. Would this even work?
2. What could go wrong with this in production?
3. Say it works, is the process of setting the maximum buffer size, an expensive one?

   I have once observed Tomcat allocating memory based on the maximum buffer size I set on a pool of connections before. So I assume there is some memory allocation (and deallocation?) going on.

Is this actually so?

Thanks.

**PLEASE NOTE**

I know about partial messages and limiting the allowed incoming message size on the OnMessage annotation. I don't want to use any of those approaches however.